# First person's account details displayed for second person when two people are logged in

Tags: java, mysql, gwt

I have an issue that when more than one person is signed onto the application it is picking up the details of the first person's account details for the second person.

When a person logs in I write their details to the server side:
Client side:

```
//Store the LoginView data for use in subsequent Views.
AsyncCallback<ViewData> callback2 = new ViewDataStoreHandler<ViewData>();
rpc.setViewData(account.getAccountId(), account.getLevel(), null, null, null, scoutGroup, null, 0, scoutGroupSection, callback2);
```

Server Side:

```
//Store and retrieve data used by Views within the application
//This allows us to securely pass parameters between Views.
private ViewData viewData = null;

public ViewData setViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel,
        String ymId, String awId, String adAwardGroup, String adScoutGroup, 
        String caId, Integer numberOfGroupsStarted, String groupSection) {

    viewData = new ViewData();

    viewData.setaccountId(accountId);
    viewData.setaccountLevel(accountLevel);
    viewData.setymId(ymId);
    viewData.setawId(awId);
    viewData.setadAwardGroup(adAwardGroup);
    viewData.setadScoutGroup(adScoutGroup);
    viewData.setcaId(caId);
    viewData.setnoGroupsStarted(numberOfGroupsStarted);
    viewData.setsection(groupSection);

    return viewData;
}
```

I then display the first view "SelectPersonView" where I get the stored information using:
Client Side:

```
//On load of page get the Account Level and ID of the account holder.
AsyncCallback<ViewData> callback = new ViewDataHandler<ViewData>(SelectPersonView.this);
rpc.getViewData(callback);
```

Server side:

```
public ViewData getViewData() {
    return viewData;
}
```

When only one person is logged in this works fine. When I have two people logged the first person's account details are displayed when the second person logs in. Your assistance greatly appreciated.

Hi Colin, this this what I implemented (I will credit you once I am sure it is working):

```
/Store and retrieve data used by Views within the application
//This allows us to securely pass parameters between Views.
public ViewData setViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel,
        String ymId, String awId, String adAwardGroup, String adScoutGroup, 
        String caId, Integer numberOfGroupsStarted, String groupSection) {
    ViewData viewData = new ViewData();

    getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true).setAttribute("viewData", viewData);
    viewData.setaccountId(accountId);
    viewData.setaccountLevel(accountLevel);
    viewData.setymId(ymId);
    viewData.setawId(awId);
    viewData.setadAwardGroup(adAwardGroup);
    viewData.setadScoutGroup(adScoutGroup);
    viewData.setcaId(caId);
    viewData.setnoGroupsStarted(numberOfGroupsStarted);
    viewData.setsection(groupSection);
    return viewData;
}

public ViewData getViewData() {
    return (ViewData) getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute("viewData");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ViewData getViewData() {
    return viewData;
}
```

Assuming this is in your `RemoteServiceServlet`, this is your problem. In a normal JavaEE server, each servlet is a singleton - there is only one instance of it. This means that all users on your webapp will share the same instance, so your server needs to find a better way of tracking data than in the same field of the same servlet instance.

One possible option is to use the [HttpSession](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19857-01/819-6518/gcxvp/index.html) class to store specific details about each browser session that is presently active. These are tracked as part of the HttpServletRequest object, and since your server-side service is also a servlet, you can use it. The method `getThreadLocalRequest()` will give you the request, and you can read and write the data into the session:

```
public void setViewData(viewDataFromClient) {
    getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true).setAttribute("key-goes-here", new ViewData());

    //...

public ViewData getViewData() {
    return (ViewData) getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute("key-goes-here");
}
```

You'll probably want to clean this up a little more, but it is a starting point. Take note of the `getSession(true)` method which creates a session if it doesn't already exist for the current client, but `getSession()` will not attempt to create it, instead insisting that it must already exist to do its work. Also make sure to make your attribute keys unique, as this session will be shared with all other servlets in this webapp. Often developers will prefix the key with the servlet class name.

---

This data will of course only exist for the duration of the session, depending on how long that has been configured to be - it might be as short as the browser quitting or the server restarting. To be keep your data around long term, look into storing data in a database of some kind (well outside the scope of a single StackOverflow answer...).

---

### Response to edit:

The added code doesn't really resolve the issue - you still have a shared field that all clients will try to read and write, so they will clobber each other's changes

```
//Store and retrieve data used by Views within the application
//This allows us to securely pass parameters between Views.
private ViewData viewData = null;

public ViewData setViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel,
        String ymId, String awId, String adAwardGroup, String adScoutGroup, 
        String caId, Integer numberOfGroupsStarted, String groupSection) {
    getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true).setAttribute
    (accountId, new ViewData());
    viewData.setaccountId(accountId);
    viewData.setaccountLevel(accountLevel);
    viewData.setymId(ymId);
    viewData.setawId(awId);
    viewData.setadAwardGroup(adAwardGroup);
    viewData.setadScoutGroup(adScoutGroup);
    viewData.setcaId(caId);
    viewData.setnoGroupsStarted(numberOfGroupsStarted);
    viewData.setsection(groupSection);
    return viewData;
}
```

Do not use the field `viewData`, unless you *expect* all users to see the same objects.

Instead, consider this code, where the ViewData is a local variable:

```
public ViewData setViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel,
        String ymId, String awId, String adAwardGroup, String adScoutGroup, 
        String caId, Integer numberOfGroupsStarted, String groupSection) {
    //create a view data object with the specific details
    ViewData viewData = new ViewData();

    viewData.setaccountId(accountId);
    viewData.setaccountLevel(accountLevel);
    viewData.setymId(ymId);
    viewData.setawId(awId);
    viewData.setadAwardGroup(adAwardGroup);
    viewData.setadScoutGroup(adScoutGroup);
    viewData.setcaId(caId);
    viewData.setnoGroupsStarted(numberOfGroupsStarted);
    viewData.setsection(groupSection);

    //store the data in the session so we remember it when the user comes back
    getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true).setAttribute(accountId, viewData);

    //return the viewdata to the user
    return viewData;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Colin. I am not a programmer so I am struggling with this. Please see my edit above. Is that correct? The key I am using is the user account passed through from the client side. From what you have written I do not think this is correct. So how do I generate the key please?